# printing decision boundary with pyplot

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, cross-validation

using pandas and sklearn to create a decision tree to learn on data where my pruning method for the tree is to retry different max depths.  I believe that i have everything working however i cannot seem to output it via pyplot.  Can somebody help me with this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

features = ['birad','age','Shape','margin','density','severity']

df = pd.read_csv('mammographic_masses.data',header=None,names=features)


df= df[df.birad != '?']
df= df[df.age != '?']
df= df[df.Shape != '?']
df= df[df.margin != '?']
df= df[df.density != '?']
#df= df[df.severity != '?']

x = df[features[:-1]]
y = df['severity']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)

depth = []
best_depth = 3
best_score = 0
best_clf = []
for i in range(1,20):
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=i)
    clf = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf,x_train,y_train,cv=10)
    ascore = clf.score(x_test,y_test)
    depth.append((i,clf.score(x_test,y_test)))
    if ascore > best_score:
            best_score,best_depth = ascore,i
            best_clf.append(clf)
print best_depth,' ',best_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, since you didn't show where you were trying to plot data: did you call

```
plt.show()
```

after generating your plots?  They won't actually be displayed until you do that.